# PHP not finding mySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I must be doing something wrong

I have a very simple script and a very simple database
No idea why it's not working..

Please help

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
if(!$link)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$database = mysql_select_db('test_db', $link);
if(!$database)
{
    die('Could not connect to database: ' . mysql_error());
}

$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT forename FROM users WHERE id='1'");
if(!$result)
    echo 'PROBLEM';
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0];

?>
```

It's not even giving any errors, just echoing 'Problem'...

The database connects fine, and there is 1 user in the database with an ID of 1 and forename is Cristian.

Comment: Try `echo mysql_error();` instead of `echo 'PROBLEM';` to get a meaningful message instead of just PROBLEM.

Comment: this may not relate at all but i would suggest not mixing mysqli and mysql calls together, if you have access to mysqli - use it for all :)

Answer (score 5):

In `$result = mysqli_query` try just useing `$result = mysql_query` same in `$row = mysqli_fetch_array` should help

Try replaceing you code from $result onward with this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT forename FROM users WHERE id='1'");
if(!$result)
    echo 'PROBLEM';
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0];

?>
```

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning?

Comment: This is the correct answer.  To elaborate, the OP is connecting using the mysql_ functions, but he is querying and fetching using the mysqli_ functions.  The mysqli_ functions are completely unaware of the connection made by mysql_ functions.  The solution is to only use mysql_ or mysqli_ functions. They can't be swapped back and forth.

Comment: The above answer does not work, it still echoes PROBLEM. Changing problem to mysql_error outputs no error. As for mixing mysql and mysqli functions, I have done so in the past and have encountered no problem, although i will change that now. I am thinking there might be a problem with php reading from the database? Any more ideas?

Comment: Alright guys it's fixed.

Removed the mysql_select_database and added it to the new mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','users').

Now all the commands are using mysqli instead of mysql.

However the error isn't working. How does mysql_error() work for mysqli? I can get the error for the $link with mysqli_errno() but what about for others?

Thanks again for all your help.